# Tuple to data frame in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an array called array list which looks like this

```
arraylist: Array[(String, Any)] = Array((id,772914), (x4,2), (x5,24), (x6,1), (x7,77491.25), (x8,17911.77778), (x9,225711), (x10,17), (x12,6), (x14,5), (x16,5), (x18,5.0), (x19,8.0), (x20,7959.0), (x21,676.0), (x22,228.5068871), (x23,195.0), (x24,109.6015511), (x25,965.0), (x26,1017.79043), (x27,2.0), (Target,1), (x29,13), (x30,735255.5), (x31,332998.432), (x32,38168.75), (x33,107957.5278), (x34,13), (x35,13), (x36,13), (x37,13), (x38,13), (x39,13), (x40,13), (x41,7), (x42,13), (x43,13), (x44,13), (x45,13), (x46,13), (x47,13), (x48,13), (x49,14.0), (x50,2.588435821), (x51,617127.5), (x52,414663.9738), (x53,39900.0), (x54,16743.15781), (x55,105000.0), (x56,52842.29076), (x57,25750.46154), (x58,8532.045819), (x64,13), (x66,13), (x67,13), (x68,13), (x69,13), (x70,13), (x71,13), (x73,13), (...
```

I want to convert it to a dataframe with two columns "ID" and value. Fo theis the code I am using is

```
val df = sc.parallelize(arraylist).toDF("Names","Values")
```

However I am getting an error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not supported
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Message tells you everything :) Any is not supported as a type of column of DataFrame. `Any` type can be caused by nulls as the second element of a tuple

Change arraylist type to `Array[(String, Int)]` (if you can do it manually; if it is deducted by Scala, then check for nulls and invalid values of second element) or create manually schema:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val arraylist: Array[(String, Any)] = Array(("id",772914), ("x4",2.0), ("x5",24.0));

val schema = StructType(
    StructField("Names", StringType, false) ::
    StructField("Values", DoubleType, false) :: Nil)
val rdd = sc.parallelize (arraylist).map (x => Row(x._1, x._2.asInstanceOf[Number].doubleValue()))

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

df.show()
```

Note: createDataFrame requires RDD[Row], so I'm converting RDD of tuple to RDD of Row

Comment: Finally after hours of head banging. Will be eternally grateful :)

Comment: @RajarshiBhadra Mapping to RDD[Row] as tricky, I've also forget about it at first ;) Just after a while I've checked my codes and see the difference

Answer (score 2):

The problem (as stated) is that Any is not a legal type to dataframe. In general legal types are primitive types (byte, int, boolean, string, double etc.), structs of legal types, arrays of legal types and maps of legal types

In your case it seems as if you used both integer and double in the second value of the tuple. If you use instead just double then it should work properly.

you can do this in two ways:
1. Make sure the original array has just double (e.g. by adding .0 at the end of each integer when you create it) or by doing a cast
2. Enforce the schema:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = new StructType()
schema.add(StructField("names",StringType))
schema.add(StructField("values",DoubleType))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(arraylist).map (x => Row(x._1, x._2.asInstanceOf[Number].doubleValue()))
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)
```

Comment: I am getting this error import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
<console>:39: error: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  (fields: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType <and>
  (fields: java.util.List[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType <and>
  (fields: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
 cannot be applied to ()
         val schema = StructType()
                      ^

Comment: @RajarshiBhadra Second argument of StructField should not have `()` - see my answer

Comment: This assumes you ran using spark-shell on spark 2.0.0 or higher. If you are running an older version replace it with sqlContext

Comment: with is I got this error (rowRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Any)], org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)
         val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)

Comment: @RajarshiBhadra I've posted full, working, tested code

Comment: Fixed my answer as per @T.Gawęda suggestion